# Generic way to access class properties

Tags: c#, oop

I have been trying to read the value from the excel sheet, map it into a dataTable and then map the value to its class in C# using reflection. There is no issue for this

I have two classes- one providing test data, and another one providing the logic to read a fixed-width file.

When the two classes have more properties, the way i access to its properties somehow duplicating.

Here is the TestData class

```
class TestData
{
     public string TestName { get; set; }
     public string Name{ get; set; }
     public string Address{ get; set; }
}

//ignoring the whole logic in the middle, i can access the value of the test by
_testData.Name or _testData.Address
```

Here is the class to access fixed-width file

```
class FieldPosition
{
     public string FieldName { get; set; }
     public string PosStart{ get; set; }
     public string PosEnd{ get; set; }
}

class IncomingFields
{
     public FieldPosition Name => GetValue("Name");
     public FieldPosition Address=> GetValue("Address");
}
//ignoring the whole logic in the middle, i can access the value of the field position by
_field.Name.PosStart or _field.Name.PosEnd
```

When TestData and IncomingFields have more properties, the code to call them becomes a big duplicating mess. Is there any way to reduce the code since the property name is the same?

Here is what i have to do per one property.

```
if (_testData.Name != "")
{
    ModifyFixedWidthFile(_testData.Name, _field.Name.PosStart, _field.Name.PosEnd)
}

if (_testData.Address!= "")
{
    ModifyFixedWidthFile(_testData.Address, _field.Address.PosStart, _field.Address.PosEnd)
}
```

Is there anyway to reduce 2 if conditions, into 1 block of code by doing a foreach loop? I just don't know how to call the properties in a generic way. is it possible to do something like this in c#

```
if (_testData.[something generic]!= "")
{
    ModifyFixedWidthFile(_testData.[something generic], _field.[something generic].PosStart, _field.[something generic].PosEnd)
}
```

Comment: Check out [AutoMapper](https://automapper.org/), it can automate copying properties from one class to another.

Comment: From the context I'm assuming that this is a typo: `ModifyFixedWidthFile(_testData.Address, _field.Name.Address, _field.Name.Address)`. Did you mean to repeat `Address`?

Comment: @ScottHannen Sorry, i fixed the mapping, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My names for methods and arguments are all close to useless here.

```
void OuterMethod(TestData testData, IncomingFields fields)
{
    ModifySomething(testData.Address, fields.Address);
    ModifySomething(testData.Name, fields.Name);
}

void ModifySomething(string value, FieldPosition fieldPosition)
{
    if (value != "")
        ModifyFixedWithFile(value, fieldPosition.PosStart, fieldPosition.PosEnd);
}
```

This just breaks it into two functions. The outer method selects a `string` property from `testData` and selects a `FieldPosition` property from `fields`. Those are the only parts that are changing. Then it calls the inner `ModifySomething` method which acts on those values.

Comment: Thanks, I tried and it seems more readable to me. Still a bit messy but it's good.